# Corrected Standard Deviation for Differences in Means

Tags: repeated-measures, measurement-error, bland-altman-plot

In the published work of Altman and Bland: Statistical Methods For Assessing Agreement Between Two Methods of Clinical Measurement, Lancet 1986 (https://www-users.york.ac.uk/~mb55/meas/ba.pdf) , page 8 in the inserted link,  the authors discussed the estimation of the standard deviation of results difference in a repeated measures framework. For example, if two different methods are used to obtain two sets of results on each subject, the corrected standard deviation of differences $s_c$ between the two methods is:

$s_c = \sqrt{{s_D}^2 + \frac{1}{4} {s_1}^2 + \frac{1}{4} {s_2}^2 }  $

where $s_1$ and $s_2$ are the standard deviations of differences between repeated measurements for the two methods separately, and $s_D$ is the standard deviation of the differences between the means of for each method. I have struggled a bit to obtain their equation from first principles. Will appreciate some hints.

Comment: Would be great if you "model" the question, for example $x_{i,j,k}$ is the $j-th$ measurement on the $i-th$ subject using method $k$ then exaplain what are the differences, averages, etc. Doing so, you will probably find the answer yourself, or will make the question readable for the users here :-)

Comment: You mean "Bland" rather than "Blan", right?

Comment: Sorry, it is Bland.